# Manage Debug and Release modes using Web.config file

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

There are two types of web config files are created in project
one Web.Debug.config and second is Web.Release.config

Is it possible to create to another configuration file like Web.Testing.config?
And if it possible how should i use the configurations in different modes of application run

for example if application in testing mode it will use connection strings in Web.Testing.config file.

please give me some suggestions on this problem.

thanks.

Comment: You can certainly create custom build configurations, whether it works with custom `web.config` files I am not 100% sure. Have you read the documentation? Also, just so you are aware VS doesn't automagically use the configuration settings in the `web.release.config`/`web.debug.config` you need to manually map them across or use a VS plugin like [slow cheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5). Sounds like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx) is what you are after.

Comment: can i configure those mapping in .csproj file of project or can i manage it from code?

Comment: so is it possible to create web.testing.config under web.config file or not?

Comment: thanks a lot James. you really saved my work. That article really helpful for me. thanks again.

Comment: You might also be interested in reading this article [ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Web.config File Transformations](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations)

Answer (score 0):

@James is right about the [slow cheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) extension for Visual Studio. It's great and I use it all the time. I believe though that you're also going to have to create a Build Configuration called Testing then (much like you normally have Debug and Release configurations). It's the build configurations that determine which `web.*.config` file gets used in Visual Studio debugging.

Also see [this MSDN article](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=214134) on using `*.config` transforms in Visual Studio. It may not be specific to `web.config` files, but `web.config` is really just special for web projects vs. the standard `app.config` used for regular windows-based programs.

Comment: I followed above MSDN article steps it works but when i place connection string in Web.testing.config file instead of Web.config it is not replaces the connection string in Web.config file?

Comment: IIRC, whatever you place in the `web.config` file trumps anything placed in the individual transforms. So, you should have the following transforms: `web.release.config`, `web.debug.config`, and `web.testing.config`. You'd have no connection string in the base `web.config` file and place a connection string specific to each build in these transforms. The resulting `web.config` file will then have the appropriate setting based on the configuration that was used to build the solution.